# Rails do you need to keep json.jbuilder files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, scaffolding

When you create scaffolds in Rails, by default, files that end in .json.jbuilder get added to the View. Are these files necessary to keep (and keep updating as you add columns to model's table) or can they be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using `jbuilder` to generate `JSON` outputs they are not necessary and you should delete them.

Comment: @Justin remember to accept answers that solve your problems :)

Comment: I will, i just had to wait the specified amount time to accept

Comment: Even if you ever do get to using JSON responses in your rails app. Never ever go for jbuilder. Resort to much nicer and easier to test ActiveModel::Serializers